# Find and print lines that have column value repeated n times

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a file:

```
scaffold_0      11498
scaffold_0      11501
scaffold_0      11728   "RHOH"
scaffold_0      12144   "RHOH"
scaffold_0      20708   "RHOH"
scaffold_0      23579   "RHOH"
scaffold_0      130818
scaffold_0      200485  "NSUN7"
scaffold_0      209928  "NSUN7"
scaffold_0      212965  "NSUN7"
scaffold_0      214055  "APBB2"
scaffold_0      223404
scaffold_0      223686  "APBB2"
scaffold_0      227687  "APBB2"
scaffold_0      306105  "APBB2"
scaffold_0      307000  "APBB2"
scaffold_0      391742
scaffold_0      399332  "UCHL1"
scaffold_0      406726  "UCHL1"
scaffold_0      482215
scaffold_0      484921
scaffold_0      538855  "LIMCH1"
scaffold_0      539051  "LIMCH1"
scaffold_0      539819
scaffold_0      543347  "LIMCH1"
scaffold_0      568182  "LIMCH1"
scaffold_0      570321
scaffold_0      570325
scaffold_0      577502  "LIMCH1"
scaffold_0      578933  "LIMCH1"
scaffold_0      621330  "PHOX2B"
scaffold_0      623303  "PHOX2B"
scaffold_0      640271
scaffold_0      667510  "gene3"
scaffold_0      679096
scaffold_0      698659  "TMEM33"
scaffold_0      700427  "TMEM33"
```

and I want to print the lines for which the items in the 3rd column are repeated 3 or more times. So that these lines are deleted:

```
scaffold_0      399332  "UCHL1"
scaffold_0      406726  "UCHL1"
scaffold_0      621330  "PHOX2B"
scaffold_0      623303  "PHOX2B"
scaffold_0      667510  "gene3"
scaffold_0      698659  "TMEM33"
scaffold_0      700427  "TMEM33"
```

I would be happy to have the order of the file kept and the lines for which the 3rd column is empty stay. 
 I tried:

```
sort -k3 file.txt | awk 'a[$3]++{ if(a[$3]>=2){ print b }; print $0}; {b=$0}'
```

Comment: Did you try anything?

Comment: Oops forgot to post that part... Updated. Thxs.

Comment: I wish you'd simply posted the output you expect rather than posting lines that you don't expect! "here's my sample input and expected output" is a lot easier to understand and test against than "here's my sample input and lines I don't expect to appear in my output".

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will remember for next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This awk reads and hashes the whole file into memory

```
$ awk '{
    a[NR]=$0              # hash to a using record number as the key for order
    c[$3]++               # $3 counter
}
END {                     # after file records have been hashed
    for(i=1;i<=NR;i++) {  # iterate in order
        split(a[i],b)     # get the 3rd column
        if(c[b[3]]>=3)    # output if count is right
            print a[i]
    }
}' file
```

Output sample:

```
...
scaffold_0      306105  "APBB2"
scaffold_0      307000  "APBB2"
scaffold_0      391742
scaffold_0      482215
scaffold_0      484921
scaffold_0      538855  "LIMCH1"
scaffold_0      539051  "LIMCH1"
...
```

Comment: Woop woop! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{c[$3]++;next} c[$3]>2' file file
scaffold_0      11498
scaffold_0      11501
scaffold_0      11728   "RHOH"
scaffold_0      12144   "RHOH"
scaffold_0      20708   "RHOH"
scaffold_0      23579   "RHOH"
scaffold_0      130818
scaffold_0      200485  "NSUN7"
scaffold_0      209928  "NSUN7"
scaffold_0      212965  "NSUN7"
scaffold_0      214055  "APBB2"
scaffold_0      223404
scaffold_0      223686  "APBB2"
scaffold_0      227687  "APBB2"
scaffold_0      306105  "APBB2"
scaffold_0      307000  "APBB2"
scaffold_0      391742
scaffold_0      482215
scaffold_0      484921
scaffold_0      538855  "LIMCH1"
scaffold_0      539051  "LIMCH1"
scaffold_0      539819
scaffold_0      543347  "LIMCH1"
scaffold_0      568182  "LIMCH1"
scaffold_0      570321
scaffold_0      570325
scaffold_0      577502  "LIMCH1"
scaffold_0      578933  "LIMCH1"
scaffold_0      640271
scaffold_0      679096
```

.

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{if ($3!="") c[$3]++;next} c[$3]>2' file file
scaffold_0      11728   "RHOH"
scaffold_0      12144   "RHOH"
scaffold_0      20708   "RHOH"
scaffold_0      23579   "RHOH"
scaffold_0      200485  "NSUN7"
scaffold_0      209928  "NSUN7"
scaffold_0      212965  "NSUN7"
scaffold_0      214055  "APBB2"
scaffold_0      223686  "APBB2"
scaffold_0      227687  "APBB2"
scaffold_0      306105  "APBB2"
scaffold_0      307000  "APBB2"
scaffold_0      538855  "LIMCH1"
scaffold_0      539051  "LIMCH1"
scaffold_0      543347  "LIMCH1"
scaffold_0      568182  "LIMCH1"
scaffold_0      577502  "LIMCH1"
scaffold_0      578933  "LIMCH1"
```